# Run FMDB processes on the same background thread?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, fmdb

I am having problems using fmdb to read and write data into the same database.

There are instances in my app where 1 class would write data into the database on the background thread while another class would read data from the same database on the main thread, both read and write processes deal with fairly large data, like a few hundred NSDictionary.

I've heard that fmdb is not "thread-safe", which will crash my app when I try to read and write in the above scenario. I've also heard suggestions to run the 2 fmdb processes on the same thread so that the app does not crash.

I've tried running them both in background threads (using NSInvocationOperation) but it crashes, I realised that they are actually running on separate background threads which caused the conflict.

So the question is, how can I make all the fmdb processes run on the same background thread so that they do not crash my app?

Or are there any alternatives handling my SQL data?

*Sorry if I didn't explain it clearly, willing to clarify.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3):

FMDatabaseQueue was made specifically for this case: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Try it out, and if it doesn't make sense- let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the latest documentation for FMDB, you will see that they now provide a queue that allows for thread-safe usage of FMDB.